# Converting Latitude/Longitude values(DMS+Compass Direction format) to corresponding Decimal Point values in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, latitude-longitude, dms

I am working on an Java android project and have the following issue. I Searched so much but still I have the problem of converting the Latitude/Longitude values that are in DMS format (Eg: 38°2'56''N, 122°9'28''W) for their corresponding Decimal Degrees format.

Example values that need to be converted for their corresponding decimal degrees format.

38°49'59''N, 26°56'59''E

38°2'56''N, 122°9'28''W

34°52'58''S, 56°10'58''W

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All you're doing when you convert DMS to decimal degrees is dividing by 60.  Divide S by 60, add it to M, divide that result by 60, then add it to D.

The second part deals with the direction that the coordinates point.  Picture a pair of axes with compass directions in their correct locations (i.e., up is N, right is E, down is S, left is W).  This means that any decimal degree value corresponding to a DMS value that pointed either S or W is going to be negative.

38°2'56''N, 122°9'28''**W** -> 38.048889, **-122.157778**

Comment: Thanks Glendon. It works....... Thanks  Sherif and Jenifer for ur quick responses. Sherifs formula is correct. Problem was the letter.

Answer (score 3):

D°M'S''

1. Divide S by 60 and get X
2. Find Y by adding X to M
3. Divide Y by 60 to get F
4. Answer = D + F

---

**SUMMARY**

TO CONVERT FROM DMS TO DEGREE

Degrees = D + ((S/60)+M)/60

Where D and M and S are the values that compose the DMS format : D°M'S''

Comment: Ya, I tried this way.. But when I do like that, for this pair of values it points to a complete different location. [38°2'56''N, 122°9'28''W]

Comment: I will check the formula wait

Comment: My formula is correct and `[38°2'56''N, 122°9'28''W]` gives 38.048889 Latitude and 122.157778 Longitude

Comment: Hi Sherif, When I go and paste both value pairs in Google map it shows 2 different places [38°2'56''N, 122°9'28''W] && [38.048889, 122.157778 ]

Comment: no way! there must be some parameter that specifies whether the input is dms or degrees or sth like that ! Missing this param is causing the difference in the localization

Comment: I saw that this format I sent is DMS+Compass Direction  http://www.geomidpoint.com/latlon.html ...... May be that N,S,E,W Letter makes the difference. I am Bit confusing with this..

Comment: try these: `[-38.048889, 122.157778]`,`[38.048889, -122.157778]` and `[-38.048889, -122.157778]` : Any gives the right location?

Comment: Thanks Sherif.. This gives the right Answer [38.048889, -122.157778]

Answer (score 1):

And you can always check your work with Sherif's formula here:
http://transition.fcc.gov/mb/audio/bickel/DDDMMSS-decimal.html

Comment: Ya, but when I go and paste these 2 value pairs in Google map it shows completely two different places. [38°2'56''N, 122°9'28''W] && [38.048889, 122.157778 ]