# How to use new Google Maps coordinates (GMS) with LatLng?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using a Google Maps object on my website to display different locations I've been to. I always used the coordinates (GGG) from the old Google Maps to set a new marker to my map. But with the new Google Maps I only get GMS format.

```
Before: 51.055207,10.524902
After: 51° 4.193', 8° 41.807'
```

My problem is, that I'm not able to use google.maps.LatLng to set a marker position anymore. If I'm typing in the new format, my map crashes and no marker is shown.

Is there another method I could use? Or do I have to convert the positions to GGG format?

Comment: with `google.maps.LatLng()` you have to use decimal format. If you have data in format like `51° 4.193'` you have to convert it to something like `51.055207`

Comment: You are asking how to convert Degrees Decimal Minutes (DDM) coordinates into Decimal Degrees (DD).  This is not hard.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945008/converting-latitude-longitude-valuesdmscompass-direction-format-to-correspond

Answer (score 0):

Use the decimal format that you used to use.  The API has not changed with the visual refresh of the maps so everything should work as usual.  If that's not working, please provide your code so we can help troubleshoot.