# Convert latitude and longitude to decimal in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmyadmin, codeigniter-3

how to convert number latitude or longitude just to decimal
convert latitude to show 2 number in front of comma
convert longitude to show 3 number in front of comma

show me code in model and view insert + view the result like in here

view insert

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Latitude</label>
    <input type="number"  class="form-control" name="latitude" id="latitude" placeholder="Latitude">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Longitude</label>
    <input type="number" name="longitude" class="form-control" id="longitude" placeholder="Longitude">
</div>
```

view result

```
<?php foreach ($pekerjaan_array as $key) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $key->no_spk; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $key->latitude; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $key->longitude; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $key->nama_vendor; ?></td>
        </tr>
                <?php } ?>
```

please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting Degree, Minutes, Seconds (DMS) to decimal in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22316348/converting-degree-minutes-seconds-dms-to-decimal-in-php)

Comment: show example of how you want it

Comment: @Dini see number formate here http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: like i input 2000 and insert to database, the when i show the result is 25.0653773 or long 233.857854 @Abdulla

Comment: how does 2000 comes as `25.0653773` ??

Comment: or when i type 12345 is automatic show the comma ?